# Configuring Rails model to only return objects from a certain year

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm building a small sports app where there are years, weeks, games and a user's picks. I built it for 2014 and now for 2015, I'm working my way back that it easily works with any year.

Currently, when I call `user.picks`, it returns all of their picks for both 2014 and 2015. I *only* want 2015 but I'm unsure to alter the structure to get just that. I'm sure it's a simple solution.

Is it possible to do without creating a `scope` on `pick`? Ideally I'd like to call `user.picks` than `user.picks.for_this_year`.

Here's my db structure:

**User.rb**

```
has_many :picks
```

**Week.rb**

```
has_many :games
has_many :picks
```

Week has attribute on it, `:year`

**Game.rb**

```
belongs_to :week
has_many :picks
```

Game has function `year` which looks at parent `week`'s year

**Pick.rb**

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :game
belongs_to :week
```

Has function `year` which look's at parent `game`'s year that it gets from parent `week`

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You need to do it in the controller, the model is just the representation of your data. The controller is the responsable for the filtering

Comment: There should be a way to do this in the model. Using `scope` is an example of that, but as mentioned, I'd like to call `.picks`. rather than `.picks.picks_this_year`

Comment: You could set a scope and use the scope in the controller. You could also set the scope up as the default scope but take care with that approach.

Comment: @margo thanks for the suggestion. can you leave an answer with setting the scope up as the default scope with the disclaimer? That's what I'm looking for, I believe and can give you credit for it.

Comment: based on @The Fabio's comment, you can do:

`default_scope { where("game.yearField >= ?", Time.now.year) }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I  would argue against removing the association between User and Pick as you will find yourself creating numerous work arounds to accommodate what is a fundamental relationship in your application.

You could set up a default_scope

```
class Pick < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope {joins(:week).where("weeks.year = ?", Time.now.year)}
end
```

A named scope is the preferred way and you could provide a conditional argument

```
class Pick < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.for_year(year=Time.now.year)
    joins(:week).where("weeks.year = ?", year)
  end
end
```

You would have to call user.picks.for_year or user.picks.for_year("2014") but your code is clearer and more maintainable. Default_scopes aren't necessarily bad but it can be easy to forget that one is created, as well as also leading to some messy workarounds.

Answer (score 1):

You could remove the `has_many :picks` from `User` model and create a custom function `picks` in your `User` Model.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  def picks
    Pick.joins(:User, :Week).where("users.id = ? and weeks.year= ?",self.id, Time.now.year).distinct
  end
end
```

Comment: One issue with this, `pick` doesn't have `year` on it. `Game` does. And `picks` belong to `games`

Comment: oh... Ok that changes the game... give me a min I will try another approach